# Why do I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" trying to connect to a database?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

This code gives me following error in visual studio 2012

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["erpConnStr"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

String validateUserQry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '" + username.Text + "'";
SqlCommand validateUserComm = new SqlCommand(validateUserQry, conn);
validateUserComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (validateUserComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == null)
{
   errorMsg.Visible = true;
   msg.Text = "Username was not Correct ! ";
}
```

The error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can tell that the error happens at this line:

```
if (validateUserComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == null)
```

Why?

Comment: Apparently, `ExecuteScalar` returns null. If you call `ToString()` on that, you get this error.

Comment: Try removing `validateUserComm.ExecuteNonQuery();`, that doesn't seem to be helping at all

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://$SITEURL$/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3):

Lose the `ToString()`:

```
if (validateUserComm.ExecuteScalar() == null)
```

Comment: The error was removed by changing
if (validateUserComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == null) 
To
if (validateUserComm.ExecuteScalar() == null)